# greenline Xcode EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on NSUserDefaults Optional

Tags: xcode

I've been writing an app that involves using NSUserDefaults to store a few Int variables and it's been working fine. I thought I was finished and was doing some final testing and one of the first lines of code that I wrote, and that has been working consistently before, has failed me.

Apparently the green line error is supposed to occur if I try to unwrap an optional that has a value of nil, but this variable is still very much an optional

```
var savedTotalSeconds: Int? = userDefaults.objectForKey("totalSecondsKey") as Int?
```

Why would this possibly return an error? It was working fine before and I only changed things I thought were unrelated to it. In the app I have a button to remove this stored value via:

```
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("totalSecondsKey")
```

What could possibly have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'as? Int' instead of 'as Int?'
The difference is that the first one tries, and might fail, at casting to Int. That failure will be captured in the optionality of the resulting variable.

The second one tries to coerce the object to 'Int?'.

Comment: @DaleBaker Could you post the relevant console logs, too?